# Running ELF file built for ARM arhitecture

Tags: linux, arm, elf, qemu

My goal is to run and debug ELF file (c444) which is compiled for the ARM architecture. I have some experience with x32 and x64 Intel architectures. However, I down know how to proceed with ARM-based architecture.

File general information is extracted below from tools `file` and `readelf`. It looks that the file is compiled for ARM architecture: ARMV5TE and ARM core: arm1022e.

```
c444: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /system/bin/linker, stripped
```

Architecture specific information

```
kali@kali:~/Downloads/samolan$ readelf -A c444 
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "arm1022e"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v5TE
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv2
  Tag_ABI_PCS_GOT_use: GOT-indirect
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed
  Tag_ABI_FP_16bit_format: IEEE 754
```

Headers

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x470
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          4480 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000200, Version5 EABI, soft-float ABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         8
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         24
  Section header string table index: 23
```

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_microarchitectures) I can see that there are many different variations of ARM architectures and one of them is ARMV5TE. I found that QEMU can emulate different AMR architectures. Hence I have tried to create a virtual ARM machine following this tutorial ([tutorial](https://www.prosysopc.com/blog/qemu-arm-test-setup/)).

Basically, I downloaded 3 files from [here](https://people.debian.org/%7Eaurel32/qemu/armel/) and run the command in the directory with downloaded files.

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -kernel vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-versatile -initrd initrd.img-2.6.32-5-versatile -hda debian_squeeze_armel_standard.qcow2 -append "root=/dev/sda1" -redir tcp:2222::22
```

In the created virtual machine I have run `uname -a` and got information that architecture can be something write (`armv5tejl`):

```
root@debian-armel:~# uname -a
Linux debian-armel 2.6.32-5-versatile #1 Wed Sep 25 00:01:55 UTC 2013 armv5tejl GNU/Linux
```

When VM started I connected to it with ssh and copied c444 file to the machine, changed the permissions `chmod 777 ./c444`, and run the command `./c444` but got an error.

```
root@debian-armel:/home/user# ./c444 
-bash: ./c444: No such file or directory
```

#### The questions

- The question is am I creating the correct environment to run this file?
- What could be a reason to get the error `-bash: ./c444: No such file or directory`.
- Maybe you could point to the direction of what images, kernels, etc. are necessary to build a system where I could run this file.
- Does somebody know what is the difference between QEMU machines and architecture?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with reverse engineering, just running a virtual machine

Answer (score 3):

“No such file or directory” is often printed by the shell when the *dynamic interpreter* of the executable is not found. You can find out which one it expects by [using `readelf-l`](https://bytefreaks.net/gnulinux/how-to-find-the-program-interpreter-that-a-linux-application-requests).